# What's a proper vertex coloring with the least possible number of colors called?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, coloring

I was wondering how a proper vertex coloring of a graph $G$ using just $\chi(G)$ colors is called. A *perfect vertex coloring*? A *chromatic vertex coloring*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a [minimum vertex coloring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumVertexColoring.html).